# How do I pass command parameters to a command from an MVVM MenuItem in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm attaching commands to the menu items in XAML.
Attaching a command without parameters works correctly.

**Here is a sample XAML menu definition:**

```
<viewModel:MenuItemVM x:Name="mnuTodoList" Content="TODO LIST" Type="Title" >
   <viewModel:MenuItemVM.Command>
      <commands:CommandTest />
   </viewModel:MenuItemVM.Command>
</viewModel:MenuItemVM>
```

I would like to pass something as simple as string or Boolean value to the command.

How do pass command parameters to a command from an MVVM Menu Item?

Comment: What you have is quite different from the typical `Command` binding but assuming `CommandTest` is a class you should be able to pass parameters  as an attribute. `<commands:CommandTest MyParam="myArg"/>`. Does `MenuItemVM.Command` not have an associated `CommandParameter` to bind to?

Comment: give a bit more code. may be the Viewmodel code. Because basically you are instantiating the menu via viewmodel. Put command specific code in both xaml as well as viewmodel

Comment: unclear question, ur posted code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: JSteward:  Thanks for your reply. Your answer was spot on and I can just pass attributes to the class.